# Batch file missing operand error, but output is correct

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have made a batch file that adds a user input number to a number stored in a text file.
The file `num1.txt` contains `268`. I open cmd and type `addToNum num1 20` and I get `Missing operand.` But when I open `num1.txt` again, it now contains `288`. So the command works, but still I get the error.

This is my script:

```
@echo off
set /a value = < C:\path\to\file\%1.txt
set /a value = %value% + %2
echo %value% > C:\path\to\file\%1.txt
```

What is the problem? And why doesn't it affect the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set /p` to get the initial value from file, not `set /a`:

```
@echo off
set /p value=<"C:\path\to\file\%~1.txt"
set /a value+=%2
echo %value%>"C:\path\to\file\%~1.txt"
```

Also use `set /a value+=%2` instead of `set /a value=%value + %2`

Comment: Thanks, now it works. But may I ask why you put `"` around the path, and why you changed `%1` to `%~1`? It worked without those changes.

Comment: Paths and files can contain whitespace, whitespace in `cmd` is seen as separators. So by double quoting, we make sure we eliminate the whitespace as a sepeator. `%~1` expands `%1` by removing any subsequent double quotes so when we use `%1` see `for /?` for more on variable expansion.

Comment: @FoxyBoi Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `cmd /?` and read the output help for Windows command processor which interprets a batch file. There is written among of lots of other useful information in last paragraph on last page that a file name (or other argument strings) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` (or `<>|` being interpreted as literal characters) must be enclosed in `"`. It is never wrong to enclose a file/folder argument string in `"`, but it can be wrong not doing that.

Comment: By the way: Much better would be as second line `set "value=0"`, as third line `for /F "usebackq" %%I in ("C:\path\to\file\%~1.txt") do set "value=%%I" & goto AddValue` (empty line(s) at top of the file are ignored), as fourth line `:AddValue`, as fifth line `if not "%~2" == "" set /A value+=%~2`, and most important as last line `>"C:\path\to\file\%~1.txt" echo %value%` with the redirection first on the command line and last `echo %value%` to write into the file also the values `1`, `2`, `3`, .., `9` correct without a trailing space. This line becomes `echo 1 1>"C:\path\to\file\test.txt"` ...

Comment: ... on execution. The last line could be also `(echo %value%)>"C:\path\to\file\%~1.txt"` which becomes on execution `(echo 1 ) 1>"C:\path\to\file\test.txt"` which writes also safely just the value `1` into the file without a trailing space. The command line `echo %value%>"C:\path\to\file\%~1.txt"` becomes with value `1` the command line `echo   1>"C:\path\to\file\test.txt"` and so the current status of command ECHO mode is written into the file instead of value `1`.